# Using a view result as allowed_options in a text(list) field

Tags: views, 8

I have a set of values that are created in a different node, and I would like to use them as the allowed values for a field in another node. So, I have a view that collect the values and I have a `hook_allowed_values` function to create the `allowed_values` list. My function is:

```
function hnbuilder_fheq_allowed_values(FieldStorageConfig $definition, ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL, $cacheable){
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
        $nid = $node->id();
    }
    $view_id = 'default';
    $args = $nid;
    $result = views_get_view_result('outcomes',$view_id,$args);
    return $result;
}
```

My problem is that my `views_get_view_result` is not returning anything. I get the correct `$nid`, and pass this to the `views...result`. The view, on its own, works fine. But if `kint($result)`, I get nothing.

I've updated the config for the field, to make it call the `hook_allowed_values` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with...

```
function hnbuilder_fheq_allowed_values(FieldStorageConfig $definition, ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL, $cacheable){
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    //kint($node->bundle());
        if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
            $thisnid = $node->get('nid')->value;
            if($node->bundle() != 'qualification'){
                $nid = $node->get('field_qualification')->target_id;
                }
        }
        $args=[$nid];
        $values = [];
        $view = Views::getView('outcomes');

        if (is_object($view)){
            $view->setArguments($args);
            $view->setDisplay('default');
            $view->execute();
            foreach($view->result as $rid=>$row){
                foreach ($view->field as $fid => $field ) {
                    $values[$rid][$fid . '-value'] = $field->getValue($row);
                    $my_options[$values[$rid]['field_fheq_code-value']] = "[".$values[$rid]['field_fheq_code-value']."]- ".$values[$rid]['field_fheq_description-value'];
                }
            }
        return $my_options;
    }
}
```